# Why do we need method outside enum constant method, though we already have different method for each constant?

Tags: java, function, enums, abstract

I am trying to make the `enum` by using the function for all the constant and defining the function for each constant say for example info for the color `GREEN` and others but why do I need to define the abstract function for the same though I have already individual functions for the every constant I have for the `enum`.

```
enum color {
    GREEN {
        public void info() {
            System.out.println("Dangerous Color: GREEN");
        }   
    },
    RED {
        public void info() {
            System.out.println("Dangerous Color");
        }
    },
    BLUE {  
        public void info() {
            System.out.println("Ordinary universal colour: BLUE");
        }    
    };         
      public void info() { System.out.println("Ordinary universal colour"); }         
    public abstract void info();    
}   
public class EnumDemo4 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        color[] c = color.values();
        for (color c1 : c) {
            System.out.println(c1);
            c1.info();    
        }
    }    
}
```

Why do we need method outside `enum` constant method, though we already have     different method for each constant?

Why do we require to add the abstract OR non abstract method though we already defined the function for respective constant?

Comment: Because otherwise the compiler can not be sure that every element in your enum has an `info()` method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code does not compile. You cannot define `info()` twice in the same enum.

This line has to be removed:
`public void info() { System.out.println("Ordinary universal colour"); }`

Anyway, when are you expecting it to work? It is not associated with any colour.

The correct definition would be like this:

```
enum Color {
    GREEN {
        @Override
        public void info() {
            System.out.println("Dangerous Color: GREEN");
        }   
    },
    RED {
        @Override
        public void info() {
            System.out.println("Dangerous Color");
        }
    },
    BLUE {  
        @Override
        public void info() {
            System.out.println("Ordinary universal colour: BLUE");
        }    
    };         

    public abstract void info();    
}
```

The reason you need to define the `abstract void info()` at enum level is because you want to enforce that **all** constants in your enumeration provide it. It is guaranteeing that all instances of the enumeration will provide it, so the line `c1.info()` in your `main()` function works.

If you try to remove the `abstract void info()`, your constants will *coincidentally* each have `info()` implemented, but nothing is telling the compiler that at the `Color` enum level, you will always have it. So it will fail to compile.

If you wanted a slightly less bulky definition you could change it like this, which does the same thing:

```
enum Color {
    GREEN("Dangerous Color: GREEN"),
    RED("Dangerous Color"),
    BLUE("Ordinary universal colour: BLUE");

    private final String info;

    Colour(String info) {
      this.info = info;
    }

    public void info() {
       System.out.println(info);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I think the `public abstract void info();` could not be removed. Otherwise, even if invoking `Color.GREEN.info()` is impossible.

Comment: I didn't refer to the abstract one. I referred to the other one because the OP had 2. I clearly said that if you remove the abstract one it will fail to compile. So its either one, or the other, not both.